# STM32L4 USART problem

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, cortex-m, cortex

I tried to develop an USART example on stm32L476 discovery kit, but I've got some problems with the HAL driver-s, I think I'm using wrong USART interface Clock enable, and USART GPIO Clock enable functions.

Here is my Code:

```
void HAL_USART_MspInit(USART_HandleTypeDef* U)
{

    RCC_APB2ENR_USART1EN;
    RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOBEN;


    GPIO_InitTypeDef G;
    G.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6 |GPIO_PIN_7;
    G.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    G.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    G.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART1;
    G.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB,&G);
}

void USART_Init()
{
    USART_HandleTypeDef U;
    U.Instance = USART1_BASE;
    U.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
    U.Init.WordLength = USART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    U.Init.Parity = USART_PARITY_NONE;
    U.Init.StopBits = USART_STOPBITS_1;
    U.Init.Mode = USART_MODE_TX_RX;
    HAL_USART_Init(&U);
}
```

And here is the driver description:

```
    The USART HAL driver can be used as follows:

  (#) Declare a USART_HandleTypeDef handle structure (eg. USART_HandleTypeDef husart).
  (#) Initialize the USART low level resources by implementing the HAL_USART_MspInit() API:
      (++) Enable the USARTx interface clock.
      (++) USART pins configuration:
        (+++) Enable the clock for the USART GPIOs.
        (+++) Configure these USART pins as alternate function pull-up.
      (++) NVIC configuration if you need to use interrupt process (HAL_USART_Transmit_IT(),
            HAL_USART_Receive_IT() and HAL_USART_TransmitReceive_IT() APIs):
        (+++) Configure the USARTx interrupt priority.
        (+++) Enable the NVIC USART IRQ handle.
        (++) USART interrupts handling:
          -@@-   The specific USART interrupts (Transmission complete interrupt,
              RXNE interrupt and Error Interrupts) will be managed using the macros
              __HAL_USART_ENABLE_IT() and __HAL_USART_DISABLE_IT() inside the transmit and receive process.
      (++) DMA Configuration if you need to use DMA process (HAL_USART_Transmit_DMA()
           HAL_USART_Receive_DMA() and HAL_USART_TransmitReceive_DMA() APIs):
        (+++) Declare a DMA handle structure for the Tx/Rx channel.
        (+++) Enable the DMAx interface clock.
        (+++) Configure the declared DMA handle structure with the required Tx/Rx parameters.
        (+++) Configure the DMA Tx/Rx channel.
        (+++) Associate the initialized DMA handle to the USART DMA Tx/Rx handle.
        (+++) Configure the priority and enable the NVIC for the transfer complete interrupt on the DMA Tx/Rx channel.

  (#) Program the Baud Rate, Word Length, Stop Bit, Parity, Hardware
      flow control and Mode (Receiver/Transmitter) in the husart handle Init structure.

  (#) Initialize the USART registers by calling the HAL_USART_Init() API:
      (++) This API configures also the low level Hardware GPIO, CLOCK, CORTEX...etc)
           by calling the customized HAL_USART_MspInit(&husart) API.

[..]
 (@) To configure and enable/disable the USART to wake up the MCU from stop mode, resort to UART API's
    HAL_UARTEx_StopModeWakeUpSourceConfig(), HAL_UARTEx_EnableStopMode() and                 
    HAL_UARTEx_DisableStopMode() in casting the USART handle to UART type UART_HandleTypeDef.
```

Unfortunately I think I missed something, but I can't figure it out. I try to search some examples, but I did not found anything.

Comment: Did you start with one of ST's supplied examples? Did it work?

Answer (score 1):

I tried generating what you want with stm32CubeMX, here is what it gives :

```
void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* huart)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  if(huart->Instance==USART1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_ENABLE();

    /**USART1 GPIO Configuration    
    PB6     ------> USART1_TX
    PB7     ------> USART1_RX 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_MspInit 1 */
  }

}
/* USART1 init function */
void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  HAL_UART_Init(&huart1);

}
```

you have to enable the peripheral clock using __HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_ENABLE()
Could also be the pull-up that you forgot...

Could you precise what the problem is? And show us your main?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example copied from STM32F4 project. You have to replace the pins and the USART instance.

```
void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

    __GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

    /**USART2 GPIO Configuration
    PA2     ------> USART2_TX
    PA3     ------> USART2_RX
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}



UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{
    __USART2_CLK_ENABLE();

    huart2.Instance = USART2;
    huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
    huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    HAL_UART_Init(&huart2);
}
```

I would like to highlight you the clock enable functions provided by HAL:

```
__GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
__USART1_CLK_ENABLE();
```

Use them to enable clock. In your current code the `RCC_APB2ENR_USART1EN;` and `RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOBEN;` are just bit positions in the clock control register. If you want to set these bits directly then it should be done something like this:

```
RCC->APB2ENR |= (APB2_EN_MASK | RCC_APB2ENR_USART1EN);
```

As you are already using HAL driver, I suggest you to use these functions they are the same for the STM32L4:

```
__GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
__USART1_CLK_ENABLE();
```

To send data use the following function:

```
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, "msg\r\n", 5, 0xFFFFFF);
```

---

And as it has been already pointed out, STMicroelectronics offers a tool called [STM32CubeMX](http://www2.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/development-tools/software-development-tools/stm32-software-development-tools/stm32-configurators-and-code-generators/stm32cubemx.html), which provides you a number of example codes and helps you initialize your hardware.